# Hibernate @Valid strange behaivor in SpringMVC

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc, uri

First, I'm very new to this, sorry if this question is dumb. I have two controllers with class request mappings and form to validate:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/creditcard")
public class CreditCardController {
    @Autowired
    //repositories

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addnewcard", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addNew(
             @ModelAttribute("newCard") @Valid CreditCard creditCard,
            BindingResult bindingResult, Principal principal, Model model) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            //render error view
        }
        creditCardService.registerNew(creditCard, principal.getName());
        return "redirect:/account";
    }
```

Another

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/account")
public class AccountController {
    @Autowired
    //repo

    @RequestMapping("")
    public String showUserProfile(Principal principal, Model model) {
        String username = principal.getName();
        User user = userService.findByUsername(username);
        Account account = user.getAccount();
        List<Payment> payers = paymentService
                .getAllPaymentsForPayerAccount(account.getId());
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("account", account);
        model.addAttribute("payers", payers);
        return "userprofile";
    }
}
```

Form on userprofile.jsp

```
<form:form cssClass="form-horizontal" modelAttribute="newCard" action="creditcard/addnewcard">
........
</form:form>
```

And all this works without `@Valid`. When I add `@Valid` it works fine, when validation fails ( shows error view with messages), but when it succeeds  I get `404` error due to incorrect URI - `http://localhost:8080/PaymentSystem/creditcard/creditcard/addnewcard`.  Here one `/creditcard` is extra, `@Valid` somehow adds this to my URI. I found to ways for me to solve this:
1) I moved `addNew` card method to 'AccountController'

2) I just removed `@RequestMapping("/creditcard")`

But still I do not found any explanation of such behaviour. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I found 3rd way to solve this issue, most suitable in this situation. I just added `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` to my action param like this:

```
<form:form cssClass="form-horizontal" modelAttribute="newCard" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/creditcard/addnewcard">
........
</form:form>
```

But still it don't know the reason of that kind of @Valid behaviour.